# With Phoenix, how can I broadcast many subtopics while rejecting out those unwanted?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a system where clients can subscribe to the following topics : `events:<start-date>` where `<start-date>` is a date. For example, `events:2018-02-01` means « channel for all the events that occur after or on the 1st Feb. of 2018 ».

When an event changes (not the date of the event, another property, for example the name of the event), or when an event gets deleted or when a new one is created, I want to broadcast all the concerned subscribers.

How can I achieve that?

There are multiple obstacles here:

1. `broadcast!("events:*", ...)` will not work (obviously, but if this would work, I would later use `handle_out` to «cancel» those who needs to be cancelled).
2. The same client (a browser, for example), can subscribe to many of these channels. Well, there are, in the same page, many views of the same calendar.
3. Even if #1 would work, Channels don't seem to keep states. (Am I mistaking? To me, each channel is a process, so there should be a way to update its state). Is there something like `Socket.assign` for channels? If Phoenix allows us to pass parameters to `join`, how can we use those parameters in the other callbacks, such as `handle_in` or `handle_out`?

Comment: How about this: create a single channel (say `events:all`), pass a start date to `join` from the client, store this join date in `socket.assigns.start_date`, and in `handle_out`, push the message to only those channels whose `assigns.start_date` is before the message's `start_date`.

Comment: Depending on how private the data is, you could just send every event down to the client and have the client filter out the events it does not care about. This may be better than `handle_out` as it is an expensive operation.

Comment: @JustinWood : Yes! But it overloads the network.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Dogbert's comment, here's my solution:

```
def join("events:all", %{"start" => start}, socket) do
    {:ok, "Hello!", assign(socket, :calendar_start, Date.from_iso8601(start))}
end

def handle_out("event_changes", event_source, socket) do
    all_events = MyApp.AppState.state(MyApp.AppState)
    client_start_date = socket.assigns.calendar_start
    if Date.compare(client_start_date, event_source.date) === :lt do
        {:noreply, socket}
    else
        filtered_events = all_events |> Enum.filter(fn (x) -> Date.compare(client_start_date, x.date) === :gt end)
        push socket, "event_changes", %{events: filtered_events}
        {:noreply, socket}
    end
end
```